# Optimizing vncscreenshot scripts

Tags: bash, process, debian, vnc

Good Day,
 I'm using vncsnapshot http://vncsnapshot.sourceforge.net/ in debian 7 environment to capture screenshots of workstations to monitor staffs desktop activity. This captures screenshot via nmap and saves it to my desired location accessed via internal web-page.

I have scripts like this . The x.x.x.x is the ip-range of the network to capture all open workstations.

```
    #!/bin/bash
 nmap -v -p5900 --script=vnc-screenshot-it --script-args vnc-screenshot.quality=30 x.x.x.x
```

And set-up in crontab to run every 5 mins.

The server has too many running processes because of it. This is the sample of ps command

```
root     32696  0.0  0.0   4368     0 ?        S    Feb23   0:00 /bin/bash /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account.sh
root     32708  0.0  0.0  14580     4 ?        S    Feb23   0:00 nmap -v -p5900,5901,5902 --script=vnc-screenshot-mb
root     32717  0.0  0.0   1952    60 ?        S    Apr10   0:00 sh -c vncsnapshot -cursor -quality 30 x.x.x.x 
root     32719  0.0  0.1  11480  4892 ?        S    Apr10   0:00 vncsnapshot -cursor -quality 30 30 x.x.x.x /var/w
root     32720  0.0  0.0   1952    60 ?        S    Apr25   0:00 sh -c vncsnapshot -cursor -quality 30 30 x.x.x.x 
root     32722  0.0  0.0   1952     4 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /bin/sh -c /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account.sh
root     32723  0.0  0.0   3796   140 ?        S    Apr25   0:00 vncsnapshot -cursor -quality 30 30 x.x.x.x /var/w
root     32730  0.0  0.0   1952     4 ?        Ss   Feb08   0:00 /bin/sh -c /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account
root     32734  0.0  0.0   4364     0 ?        S    Feb08   0:00 /bin/bash /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account.
root     32741  0.0  0.0  13700     4 ?        S    Feb08   0:00 nmap -v -p5900 --script=vnc-screenshot-account --
root     32755  0.0  0.0   1952     4 ?        Ss   Feb08   0:00 /bin/sh -c /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account.sh
root     32757  0.0  0.0   1952     4 ?        S    Feb07   0:00 sh -c vncsnapshot -cursor -quality 30 30 x.x.x.x 
root     32760  0.0  0.0   3796     0 ?        S    Feb07   0:00 vncsnapshot -cursor -quality 30 30 x.x.x.x /var/w
root     32762  0.0  0.0   4368     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /bin/bash /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account.sh
root     32764  0.0  0.0   4368     0 ?        S    Feb08   0:00 /bin/bash /var/www/vncsnapshot/.scripts/.account.sh
```

How can I optimize this set-up to close un-nessesary processes that are still running.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have less `vncsnapshot` processes, or less other background processes? In the long term, I'd get a bigger server.

Comment: Just less vncsnapshot processes. Is my script corret by the way of execution? It's working as intended . 'm just bothered by the number of process by the vncsnapshot

Comment: i split the processes in two part: nmap that regularly scan the network and the vncsnapshot that grab screenshot of a list of previously scanned host. Also i'd implement a lock system otherwise nmap launch capture each time is running

Comment: @m47730 Can you give me an example on how to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I split the processes in two part: nmap that regularly scan the network and the vncsnapshot that grab screenshot of a list of previously scanned host.
In my opinion, in this way the things are cleaner.

**i haven't test this code**

```
#!/bin/bash

## capture the list of host with vnc port open

list=/dev/shm/list
port=5900
network=192.168.1.*

nmap -n -p${port} --open ${network} -oG - | grep 'open\/tcp' | awk '{print $2}' > ${list}
```

the other script, check if a process is alive with lock file and in case launch the grab command

```
#!/bin/bash

list=/dev/shm/list
run=/run/vncscreenshot/

mkdir -p ${run} &>/dev/null
cat ${list} |\
while read host 
  do
  lock="${run}/${host}.lock"
  test -e ${lock} && ps -p $(<${lock}) &>/dev/null && continue
  vnc-screenshot-it vnc-screenshot.quality=30 ${host} &
  echo $! > ${lock}
  done
```

Comment: Ok , I will try to test this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ize i fixed a bug, if something is not working add a comment and i tried to fix it